# react-bootstrap collapse and Fade module not found

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-dom

Module versions :

> "react": "^15.6.2", "react-bootstrap": "^0.32.1" & "react-dom":
>   "^15.6.2",

Compilation Errors :

> ERROR in ./node_modules/react-bootstrap/es/Collapse.js Module not
>   found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-transition-group/Transition' in
>   '/Users/dashe01/Documents/GitHub/perpetual_pencil/ui/node_modules/react-bootstrap/es'
>   @ ./node_modules/react-bootstrap/es/Collapse.js 13:0-99 36:60-66
>   36:98-105 36:139-147 36:181-188 195:6-16  @
>   ./node_modules/react-bootstrap/es/index.js  @
>   ./src/components/sketches/components/nodes/HTTPMethods.js  @
>   ./src/components/sketches/components/nodes/APIProperties.js  @
>   ./src/components/sketches/components/APIs.js  @ ./src/routes.js  @
>   ./src/index.js  @ multi
>   (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:8090 whatwg-fetch
>   webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8090
>   webpack/hot/only-dev-server babel-polyfill ./src/index.js
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/react-bootstrap/es/Fade.js Module not found:
>   Error: Can't resolve 'react-transition-group/Transition' in
>   '/Users/dashe01/Documents/GitHub/perpetual_pencil/ui/node_modules/react-bootstrap/es'
>   @ ./node_modules/react-bootstrap/es/Fade.js 12:0-82 77:48-56 77:78-85
>   95:6-16  @ ./node_modules/react-bootstrap/es/index.js  @
>   ./src/components/sketches/components/nodes/HTTPMethods.js  @
>   ./src/components/sketches/components/nodes/APIProperties.js  @
>   ./src/components/sketches/components/APIs.js  @ ./src/routes.js  @
>   ./src/index.js  @ multi
>   (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:8090 whatwg-fetch
>   webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8090
>   webpack/hot/only-dev-server babel-polyfill ./src/index.j

I just installed react-bootstrap module but during compilation, I encountered the above errors. Unable to resolve the same. Is there any version dependency that is causing these errors?

Comment: npm i react-transition-group@^1

Comment: @jsDevia after installing I am getting following compile error "ERROR in ./node_modules/react-addons-css-transition-group/index.js"